# AngularJS: Wrapping directive in a directive

Tags: angularjs

I am wrapping ui-bootstrap's typeahead directive in another directive, because I'll be using the same code for numerous times. For example, I'll be using the same code for more than 7 times in the app:

```
<input type="text" name="name"
    ng-model="thisCtrl.name"
    typeahead="data.name for data in requestHttp($viewValue)"
    typeahead-on-select="thisCtrl.id = $item.id"
    typeahead-template-url="thisTemplate.html>
```

which is extremely verbose and non-DRY to implement. However, typeahead does not seem to recognize my ng-model, and does not change after selecting an item from the dropdown list.

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cW6fhjNma8GrkhcrMCZZ?p=preview) for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I think it's because you have an isolate scope on the wrapping directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** (*11/12/14*):

Hypothetically, my directive is having a conflict with typehead's `ng-model`. `bindToController` was not causing any problems.

**See [updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JshO9Lu5ZNuno5cvdEeR?p=preview).**

**Old Answer**:

Your `bindToController` made the constructor kinda override the directive scope,  so it wasn't binding properly.

> **Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FgvHl3IomkyYN4hZ3q7l?p=preview)**

```
function exTypeahead($compile) {
 return {
   scope: {
    http: '@exTypeahead',
    model: '=ngModel'
   },
   restrict: 'A',
   link: linkFn,
   //bindToController: true,
   controllerAs: 'exTypeaheadCtrl',
   controller: 'exTypeaheadController',
   template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="model" typeahead="data.name for data in exTypeaheadCtrl.request($viewValue)" class="form-control" /></div>',
   replace: true
  };

  function linkFn(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    ctrl.http = scope.http;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. But I must ask (if this is not too much) for any additional info about bindToController on why it overrides the directive scope? I'll take my research as well. Is this an Angular issue or an unintentional effect?

Comment: I think it just means make them the same so your directives scope is bound as the controller instead of like `ctrl.model` in this case, but then it seems like when your pass in an isolate scope variable you get a conflicting double model error.

Comment: In case anyone else is confused like I was: `http: '@exTypeahead'` doesn't need to be called "http" for any specific reason. It's just a way for the `<ex-typeahead="someURL">` directive to pass someURL down to the exTypeaheadController as a scope variable, `$scope.http` from that controller's perspective. I would have called it "src" if I was implementing this solution, and the controller would then do `$http.get($scope.src)` instead. All is clear if you read the Plunker's code!

Comment: For some reason, I noticed that ```bindToController``` was not actually causing problems. Hypothetically, my directive's ```ng-model``` seems to be having a conflict with typeahead's ```ng-model```. Here's a [plunkr of the updated one](http://plnkr.co/edit/JshO9Lu5ZNuno5cvdEeR?p=preview).